# Integrating Flink with Datadog

Tags: apache-flink, graphite, flink-streaming, flink-cep, datadog

I am having several issues regarding Flink and Datadog integration. First, the issue is that Datadog uses dogstatsD instead of statsD which is not included in Flink documentation

[image]

Another issue is that if you go to Datadog's [Integrations](https://app.datadoghq.com/account/settings#integrations) page, Flink integration is missing. I have tried installing graphite but I am having several issues with that as well due to python 3.6, I tried virtualenv as well, but thought of going with datadog, which is giving me hard time as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches that may work:

1. It looks like flink has an [HTTP connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/metrics.html#datadog-orgapacheflinkmetricsdatadogdatadoghttpreporter) to send metrics to Datadog, which at first glance looks to send over the Datadog metrics API instead of dogstatsd.
2. Dogstatsd is not very different from statsd otherwise, so it's often easy to modify statsd libraries to work for dogstatsd. [This project on GitHub](https://github.com/drivetribe/flink-metrics-datadog-statsd/blob/master/README.md) seems to be such a project, and may come in handy.